mpi cluster debugger
I am trying to debug an MPI application using Intel MPI and Fortran in Visual Studio 2019. When I press F5 to start debugging, it does not work. There is no MPI CLUSTER DEBUGGER in Debugging > Debugger > Debugger Type. There is only Native Only. Ctrl+f5 works correctly. Also run manually from command window works too. but cant f5. what can i do?
i have done
Command: "path\to\mpiexec.exe"
Command Arguments: -n 6 "$(TargetPath)"
Working Directory: $(OutDir)
Environment: PATH=path\to\bin;$(PATH)

MPICLUSTERDEBUGGER was removed on Visual Studio starting from VS2012, which explains why Ctrl+F5 & command line work but F5 failed. You may need to grab a old version of VS or submit feature request on VS developer community.
